# Is there are more concise way than using position() for multiple conditions in XPath?

Tags: xpath

In XPath you can use `*[position()=1 or position()=last()]` to get both the first and last matching node. However, if you want either just the first or last node you can use `*[1]` or `*[last()]` respectively. Trying to use something like `*[1 or last()]` selects all nodes. Is there a more concise way of joining the conditions?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **No**. There is no more concise way than `[position()=1 or position()=last()]` that make sense for this purpose.

Regarding this predicate that you tried `[1 or last()]` :

- number `0` translated to boolean `False` and the rest translated to `True`.
- `last()` returns position index of the last element in context

Given above rules, this kind of predicate expressions `[1 or last()]` always translated to `[True or True]` which evaluates to `True`, that's why you get *all nodes* using this predicate.

Comment: Thanks for that. However, I did manage to shorten it a bit: `*[1] | *[last()]`!

Comment: @CJDennis Yes, I'm aware of that trick, and that's definitely shorter for this particular situation. By using union (`|`) operator like that, you need to repeat everything before the predicate, so the overall expression length doubles as the path gets deeper. CMIIW